# Argument labels '(URL:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

I'm trying to convert my code to Swift 3 and I get this error:

> Argument labels '(URL:)' do not match any available overloads

```
let viewController = VisitableViewController(URL: URL)
```

Here is my entire code:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController = UINavigationController()
var session = Session()


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    visit(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9292/")!)
    return true
}

func visit(URL: NSURL) {
    let viewController = VisitableViewController(URL: URL)
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    session.visit(viewController)
}
```

Here is the VisitableViewController :

```
import UIKit

open class VisitableViewController: UIViewController, Visitable {
    open weak var visitableDelegate: VisitableDelegate?

    open var visitableURL: URL!

    public convenience init(url: URL) {
        self.init()
        self.visitableURL = url
    }

    // MARK: Visitable View

    open private(set) lazy var visitableView: VisitableView! = {
        let view = VisitableView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    fileprivate func installVisitableView() {
        view.addSubview(visitableView)
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: [ "view": visitableView ]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[view]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: [ "view": visitableView ]))
    }

    // MARK: Visitable

    open func visitableDidRender() {
        self.title = visitableView.webView?.title
    }

    // MARK: View Lifecycle

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        installVisitableView()
    }

    open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        visitableDelegate?.visitableViewWillAppear(self)
    }

    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        visitableDelegate?.visitableViewDidAppear(self)
    }

    /*
     If the visitableView is a child of the main view, and anchored to its top and bottom, then it's
     unlikely you will need to customize the layout. But more complicated view hierarchies and layout 
     may require explicit control over the contentInset. Below is an example of setting the contentInset 
     to the layout guides.

    public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        visitableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topLayoutGuide.length, left: 0, bottom: bottomLayoutGuide.length, right: 0)
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: You need to show us `VisitableViewController` constructors.

Comment: Please ⌘-click on `VisitableViewController` and look up the proper method in the header file.

Comment: @vadian it's coming from the UIKits framework, I've updated it bellow my code.

Comment: Yes, check out my comment. @AbhishekJain

Comment: Regardless of where the declaration is coming from the easiest way to figure out signatures by yourself is to ⌘-click on the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
func visit(url: URL) {
    let viewController = VisitableViewController(url: url)
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    session.visit(viewController)
}
```

That's using `url:` instead of `URL:` for the `VisitableViewController` initializer. I'd also suggest following that same convention with `visit`, and also replacing the `NSURL` with `URL`.

Comment: Thank you it's working! I also had to update this line visit(url: URL(string: "https://localhost:9292/")!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code-

```
func visit(URL: NSURL) {
    let viewController = VisitableViewController(url: URL)
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    session.visit(viewController)
}
```

Change -

```
visit(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9292/")!)
```

to

```
visit(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:9292/")!)
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I get 'Cannot convert value of type 'URL.type' to expected argument type 'URL'

Comment: Yeah, I marked it as correct. It's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the viewDidLoad

```js
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "YourTitle";
```

and is working!